# Stack rows from two tables on top with different number of columns

Tags: sql

I would like to add the row from table_2 for the customer_id below to table_1 to get something like the desired output table (see below).
A union would not work as the column names are different for the country column

table_1

```
customer_id | first_name | last_name | country_name
32            John          Doe        Canada
```

table_2

```
customer_id | first_name | last_name | country | city
32            John          Doe        Canada    Toronto
```

Desired output table

```
customer_id | first_name | last_name | country
32            John          Doe        Canada 
32            John          Doe        Canada
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a union query here:

```sql
SELECT customer_id, first_name, last_name, country FROM table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT customer_id, first_name, last_name, country FROM table_2
ORDER BY customer_id;
```

Note that we are not including the `city` column from `table_2` in the above query.  This is fine, so long as the number and types of the column we do include in the union match each other from both tables.

Comment: I was thinking of a union as well but what if the column names are different or the table has a lot of columns? (see example above)

Comment: None of that matters, as my answer says, only that the number and types of columns must agree.